# C# Twilio <Say> Verb - Can it be passed in as a string rather than a URL URI?

Tags: c#, twilio

I used Twilio's example code to successfully make a call - but I would like to instead pass in a string - as opposed to Twilio going to the URL to get the XML file to parse.

Does anyone know if it is possible?

A sample or at least getting me pointed in that direction would be appreciated too.

Thank you in advance!!

```
public class TwilRestCall
{

    public void testCall_Send()
    {

        const string accountSid = "sdfsf...";
        const string authToken = "fghfghf...7;
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken); 

        var to = new PhoneNumber("+15551212");
        var from = new PhoneNumber("+15551213");

         // Would prefer to pass in string instead of having it go to URL
        var call = CallResource.Create(to, from, url: new Uri("https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/blahblah_Or_Use_Azure_Live_Or_Link_FromnGrokTesting"));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

The `url` parameter of the Create method is used to point Twilio to the specific TwiML that it will get and parse once the call connects successfully. We currently do not have a way to pass that TwiML string to Twilio from the method call.

However, you can setup an API of sorts that hosts an XML file (and this file would contain your TwiML string). Then you could use ngrok (if you're doing local development) to expose the URL of that file to Twilio. I'm not sure if this helps, but I hope it clears up any confusion. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Thanks Corey - I've been using nGrok for testing, I noticed latency from when the call picked up to the time the code was spoken and assumed it was latency on the Azure side - besides not having to push files would involve less overhead.  Appreciate the clarity and at least knowing this is how I need to preoceed.  Thank you again!!

Comment: No problem! Glad this helps.